# C - Making sure user input is of appropriate length

Tags: c, newline, fgetc

Something that I thought that would be pretty basic has me stumped.

If I have a `char` array `char menuInput[3];` and do `fgets(menuInput,3,stdin);`, I can easily check if they entered nothing:

```
if(menuInput[0]=='\n')
   {
    printf("******You made no selection.******");
   }
```

Or if they entered too many (in this case, more than one) characters:

```
else if(menuInput[1]!='\n')
{
   printf("******Invalid Selection: Please enter a single digit option.******");
   break;
 }
```

In that case, the user is entering either no characters, exactly the right amount (one), or too many.

What is giving me trouble is checking when they could either enter no characters, up to `n` amount, or too many.

If I have `char surname[SURNAME_MAX + 1];`, and use `fgets(surname,SURNAME_MAX + 1,stdin);` where `SURNAME_MAX` is 12, I can't work out how to check whether the input falls within the 'acceptable' range.

I can easily see if the user has inputted anything at all (`if surname[0]='\n'`) and if they have entered exactly 12 characters (with the 13th being the `'\n'`).

I think the crux of things is here is just making sure that, somewhere, `surname[SURNAME_MAX + 1]` contains '\n', but I don't know how to do that in C.

Regards,

Doug

<strike>EDIT: Ok, I'm going with @R Sahu's answer, but am having trouble making it work properly.</strike>

I'm expecting, at most, the 12 characters defined by SURNAME_MAX.

This should mean that, by that answer, my array should be `surname[SURNAME_MAX+3]` ("need at least SURNAME_MAX+2 just to store the newline and the terminating null character")

Then I `fgets(surname,SURNAME_MAX + 3,stdin);` and then is it supposed to be:

```
while(strlen(surname)>SURNAME_MAX+2);
      {
         printf("Input is too long!\n");
         printf("Surname (1-12 characters): ");
         fgets(surname,SURNAME_MAX + 2,stdin);
      }
```

?

Is that the correct way of implementing the answer?

It looks right to me, but, no matter what I enter, I'm getting the "Input is too long!" message.

EDIT 2: My bad, had some code in the wrong place, all good now.

Comment: `char menuInput[2];` and do `fgets(menuInput,3,stdin);` well you have trouble, it has to be `char menuInput[3];` and do `fgets(menuInput, 3, stdin);`

Comment: Why not use `getline` instead?

Comment: @tourniquet_grab `getline()` is a gnu extension AFAIK.

Comment: @iharob Yes, it is a POSIX 2008 extension.

Comment: @iharob Whoops, typo I meant to type `menuInput[3];`, good pickup though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said:

> What is giving me trouble is checking when they could either enter no characters, up to n amount, or too many.

My suggestion: If you are expecting to see at most `N` characters, create an array whose size is larger than `N+2`. You need at least `N+2` just to store the newline and the terminating null character, and use `fgets` on that string. If the length of the string is greater than `N+1`, then you know they entered too many characters. Detecting whether they entered too few characters is simple. I think you will be able to figure it out.

Comment: That's not a half-bad idea, I'll give it a shot, thanks.

Comment: OK, I certainly see how that is supposed to work, but I'm having trouble making it happen. I've edited my post with details about how I've tried it.

Comment: You have a `;` at the line `while(strlen(surname)>SURNAME_MAX+2);`. That is not right. The following block is always executed since the `while` loop terminates at the `;`. If you enter than `12` characters, the `while` statement will never terminate.

Comment: Yep, just saw that now, but there was another issue elsewhere as well! All good now, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

For finding character in string, you can use strchr method:

```
  char *pch;
  pch=strchr(SURNAME,'\n');
  if (pch != NULL)
    {
      // ok we've got \n in string
    }
```

But I'm not sure it is the best way to solve *this* problem at all.

Comment: This is absolutely unrelated to the question.

Comment: Last paragraph "making sure that, somewhere, surname[SURNAME_MAX + 1] contains '\n'". I said, that it's not a proper way to do it in general, but for checking existence of character in string, *this* method can be used.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question, you could post a comment on that, but this is not the answer, the answer involves `fgets()` with a larger array and `strlen()` just as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest separating user input from variable checking/assignment.

First read in user input

```
 char buf[100];
 if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
   // EOF or IO error occurred. 
   return;
 }
```

Now qualify input; various methods exist.

```
 int len = strlen(buf);
 // lop off potential \n
 if (buf > 0 && buf[len-1] == '\n') buf[--len] = 0;
 if (len >= sizeof surname) {
   // Input too long
   return;
 }
 memcpy(surname, buf, len + 1);
```